# How to use the OpenOffice spell checker in PB Application with OLE Object?

Tags: openoffice.org, spell-checking, powerbuilder

I am using OpenOffice in my system and already I tried about it,  also i got the solution from the CodeExchange examples but i couldn't get the spell checker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get something useful from this [tutorial on using the OpenOffice spellchecker with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/OOSpellCheck.aspx).